# Which Port to Use For MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, port

I am trying an example at Spring 3 with MongoDB. I can reach MongoDB's interface on port 28017. However examples use 27017 in configuration files. Which one to use?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

28017 is admin interface and admin operations can be checked from there via web. However when using MongoDb at applications 27017 should be defined as port. When trying to reach that port given information is that:

```
You are trying to access MongoDB on the native driver port. For http diagnostic access, add 1000 to the port number
```

Comment: @kamaci, I can understand the theory in your answer, but I can't develop actionable steps to fix the problem(not a pro). I am using Ubuntu Desktop 13. What are the commands and steps I need to execute to fix the conflict? Thank you!

Comment: i am trying to access mongodb from the web browser using Meteor, once i try using the the localhost with that port i got this error msg "You are trying to access MongoDB on the native driver port. For http diagnostic access, add 1000 to the port number". anyidea how i can resolve this error and how i can query from the web browser

Answer (score 0):

I find it very interesting by doing a very stupid thing. Added 1000 to 27017 and it become 28017, I access localhost:28017 and the admin panel appeared.

best of luck

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do not use default port in your application.
that is the first hackers are looking for.